# How to use Proxies in Ethers?

Tags: ethers.js, openzeppelin, error, delegatecall, proxy-contracts

I'm trying to use Proxies in Ethers.

My Solidity file:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/proxy/transparent/TransparentUpgradeableProxy.sol"; // to use via getContractFactory()

contract Test {
    string public constant message = "Hello, world!";
}
```

**I will try to read `message` from a Proxy.**

I see 2 options:

1. Call `message()` on an instance of `TransparentUpgradeableProxy` (doesn't work)
2. Call `message()` on an instance of `Test` attached to the Proxy's address (doesn't work)

My script:

```
const { expect } = require("chai");
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

describe("Test", function () {

  it("Should be able to read message from proxy", async function () {

    // Get Signer
    const signer = await hre.ethers.getSigner();

    // Get Contract Factories
    const Test = await ethers.getContractFactory("Test");
    const Proxy = await ethers.getContractFactory("TransparentUpgradeableProxy");

    // Deploy Contract
    const test = await Test.deploy();
    await test.deployed();

    // Deploy Proxy
    const proxy = await Proxy.deploy(test.address, signer.address, []);
    await proxy.deployed();

    // Attach Contract ABI to Proxy Address
    const proxy2 = await Test.attach(proxy.address);

    console.log(await test.message()); // to make sure it works
    try { console.log(await proxy.message()) } catch (err) { console.log(err.message) } // option 1
    try { console.log(await proxy2.message()) } catch (err) { console.log(err.message) } // option 2
  });
});
```

Output:
[image]

Help?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

Option 2 (attaching the Contract to the Proxy's address) is the right way.

It was failing for me, because of this line: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v4.5.0/contracts/proxy/transparent/TransparentUpgradeableProxy.sol#L122

Now, I'm calling message from a non-admin address, like this:

```
await proxy2.connect(nonAdmin).message()
```

And it works.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of things going on here.

1. To deploy a proxy you must actually initialize the `logic` address in the constructor. You should hence do something along the lines of

   ```
    contract Test is TransparentUpgradeableProxy {
      constructor(
         address _logic,
         address _admin_,
         bytes memory _data
      ) payable TransparentUpgradeableProxy(_logic, _admin, _data) {}
    }
   ```

Where the `_logic` is the address of the contract you are trying to proxy. That should set you off on actually deploying a proxy

2. As to `await test.message()` it does not work because the contract itself does not have a `message` function. I don't think solidity provides default getters and setters so you'd need to implement them yourself.

Comment: `Test` is the `_logic` contract, not the proxy. I'm already passing its address to the Proxy in my script.